# g++-4.8.1 thinks that an explicitly-declared destructor with no exception specification is always noexcept(true)

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

Consider the following program:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Thrower
{
    ~Thrower() noexcept(false) { throw 1; }
};

struct Implicit
{
    Thrower t;
};
static_assert(!std::is_nothrow_destructible<Implicit>::value, "Implicit");

struct Explicit
{
    ~Explicit() {}

    Thrower t;
};
static_assert(!std::is_nothrow_destructible<Explicit>::value, "Explicit");
```

With `g++-4.8.1`, there is a static assertion failure on `Explicit` -- it seems to think that `~Explicit()` is `noexcept`. This does not match my expectations. According to §12.4.3:

> A declaration of a destructor that does not have an exception-specification is implicitly
>   considered to have the same exception-specification as an implicit declaration

The funny thing here is the check of `Implicit` seems to be behaving according to my interpretation of §15.4.14 (through §12.4.7).

> ...If *f* is an...destructor...it's implicit exception-specification specifies...f has the exception-specification `noexcept(true)` if every function it directly invokes allows no exceptions.

`g++-4.7` lacks `is_nothrow_destructable`, I wrote my own to check the behavior in 4.7. The program seems to compile perfectly fine. I reserve the right for this to be completely wrong and the source of my confusion:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_nothrow_destructible
{
    static constexpr bool value = noexcept(std::declval<T>().~T());
};
```

**TL;DR:** Why does `g++-4.8.1` think that an explicitly-declared destructor with no exception specification is *always* `noexcept(true)`?

---

**Update**: I opened a bug on this: [57645](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57645). If you really need to work around this issue, you can add an exception specification to the destructor (like `Thrower` has in the example).

Comment: And that's how Andy Prowl wrote an answer with 1000+ upvotes.

Comment: @H2CO3: lol, no, I just think this is a compiler bug and I have zero chance to say anything relevant about it ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> TL;DR: Why does g++-4.8.1 think that an explicitly-declared destructor with no exception specification is always `noexcept(true)`?

Because it has a bug?

Your interpretation of the standard is correct, and Clang implements it correctly (the assert doesn't fire).

> `f` has the exception-specification `noexcept(true)` if **every function it directly invokes** allows no exceptions.

A destructor directly invokes the destructor of all subobjects:

`§12.4 [class.dtor] p8`:

> After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any automatic objects allocated within the body, **a destructor for class `X` calls the destructors for X’s direct non-variant non-static data members**, [...].

Comment: Oh yeah, please file a bugreport [over at GCC's bugtracker](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/).

Comment: I was hoping I was wrong instead of the compiler...it is a much more comfortable thing. I opened a bug on it.